# Call to undefined function yii\web\mb_strlen()

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I`m using Amazon server with Amazon Linux AMI.
I install

```
yum install php55 php55-mysql php55-pdo
```

and went I run my project (with Yii2 framework) it give me

```
Call to undefined function yii\web\mb_strlen()
```

I try to install mb_strlen from here

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

but this form php5.3 and there is no for php5.5

How can I install mb_string for php5.5 ?

Answer (score -1):

The problem isn't that the script is calling a function from the multibyte extension, it's the fact that the call is being namespaced to `yii\web` rather than in the global namespace, so PHP is searching for `\yii\web\mn_strlen()`.

If you can identify where the call is made (e.g. through a stack dump or debug backtrace), it should be to `\mb_strlen()`

Comment: I change it to \mb_strlen() and I got
Call to undefined function mb_strlen() ,mb string is still missing